# Are web page data files stored locally for a time?

Tags: web

When we hit any URL( like Facebook.com) on any browser(like chrome) it uses many resources for that particular page like JS files, Images, properties files etc. So, are they stored locally temporarily ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called the browser cache :-) Websites can also use local storage to store some data on your machine. Additionally along the way various servers might cache the resources. ISPs do this a lot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KenY-N actually it's 100% accurate and perfectly answers the question

Comment: @KevinNagurski so , all these javascript files gone present in browser local cache that is local storage and I can access it. I can change it but it should be temporarily.when ever page  reloaded the new entries are gone create. right  ?